# Angular AWS Amplify Build Not working - Time Out error

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, cicd

I am using AWS Amplify to host Angular App. Everything was working fine till Friday 3rd June but after that my build's are failing with Timed out error. Build's are also not going beyond **ES5 bundle generation complete** step.
Attached are error logs

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zBdj.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Ru4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I'm having same issue:

**Build settings:**

```
Build image: Amazon Linux 2
Build timeout: 30
Amplify CLI: 4.52.0
```

**amplify.yml**

```
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: angular
    backend:
      phases:
        build:
          commands:
            - amplifyPush --simple
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - nvm use $VERSION_NODE_14
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli@10.1.7
        build:
          commands:
            - nvm use $VERSION_NODE_14
            - ng build --configuration=$BUILD_ENV --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: dist/myapp
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
```

Error:

```
Build failed to complete successfully. Reason: Build timed out

                                # Starting phase: build
2022-06-06T20:04:49.212Z [INFO]: # Executing command: nvm use 14
2022-06-06T20:04:49.447Z [INFO]: Now using node v14.19.0 (npm v6.14.16)
2022-06-06T20:04:49.447Z [INFO]: # Executing command: ng build --configuration=production --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer
2022-06-06T20:04:50.017Z [WARNING]: Your global Angular CLI version (14.0.0) is greater than your local version (10.1.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.
                                    To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
2022-06-06T20:04:51.760Z [WARNING]: Option "extractCss" is deprecated: Deprecated since version 11.0. No longer required to disable CSS extraction for HMR.
2022-06-06T20:04:51.760Z [WARNING]: 
2022-06-06T20:04:54.790Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:04:54.956Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:04:54.989Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:04:58.596Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:04:58.598Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
                                    Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:04:59.585Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:04:59.857Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:04:59.932Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:00.363Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:00.697Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:00.726Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:00.773Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:00.966Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:01.070Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:01.322Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:01.350Z [WARNING]: Compiling @ngrx/store : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:01.644Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:02.073Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:02.286Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:02.308Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:02.489Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:02.834Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:02.928Z [WARNING]: Compiling @ngrx/store-devtools : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:03.028Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:03.374Z [WARNING]: Compiling @almothafar/angular-signature-pad : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:03.554Z [WARNING]: Compiling ngx-webcam : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:03.608Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:03.756Z [WARNING]: Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:03.875Z [WARNING]: Compiling ng2-charts : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:04.080Z [WARNING]: Compiling ngx-captcha : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:04.200Z [WARNING]: Compiling ngx-quill : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:04.378Z [WARNING]: Compiling ngx-extended-pdf-viewer : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:04.427Z [WARNING]: Compiling @iplab/ngx-color-picker : es2015 as esm2015
2022-06-06T20:05:05.690Z [WARNING]: - Generating browser application bundles...
2022-06-06T20:06:41.022Z [WARNING]: ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
```

**Solution:**

This was the clue:
`Your global Angular CLI version (14.0.0) is greater than your local version (10.1.7)`

For me it was a mismatch between global angular cli version and local version, I was installing latest angular cli version, so I just added the local version in preBuild stage and it works fine now.